# Jquery capture dynamic id

Tags: jquery

I have a question, could you please help me?

I have the following code...

```
$("#ativ").each(function(){
      if(this.id){
        this.id = "ativ[" + counter +"]";
        ativ = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(ativ);
      }
    });

// This part is ok!
// Now I want to capture the onChange event of this new renamed id
// How do I do????
    $("#"+ativ).live("click",function() {
        alert('Hello world!');
    });

// This piece of code is not working!
```

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this markup from, but it's not valid. Please look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), so the next post you make isn't as much of a mess.

Comment: The id of `#ativ` will always be `ativ`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

update the event listener everytime the id changes

```
$("#ativ").each(function(){
      if(this.id){
        this.id = "ativ[" + counter +"]";
        ativ = $(this).attr("id");

        // your listener here
        $("#"+ativ).click(function() {
          alert('Hello world!');
        });

      }
    });
```

-OR-

identify the div using its class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery >= 1.7 you should use the method `on()`.

ex:

```
$("body").on("click", ativ, function(){
     alert('Hello world!');
});
```

Please have a look into the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)